# Can you create std::map with only keys?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, containers

So, I want to use `std::map` to find if an element exists. So I basically only need the key, not any value.

Is there any way to do something like `std::map<std::string, void>` for example? Or is there a better alternative to `std::map` for this kind of stuff?

Worst case scenario a different container like `std::vector<std::string>` could be used, but I'm curious if you can do this with `std::map` (`std::map<std::string, bool>` could also be used, but the bools would be wasted memory).

Comment: Use a `std::set`.

Comment: If all you care about is if something exists and you don't need the data in any particular order use `std::unordered_set`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Or is there a better alternative to std::map for this kind of stuff?

Yes. The container that you describe is a set. There are `std::set` and `std::unordered_set` corresponding to their map counterparts in the standard library.